# Mux return if variable not defined?

Tags: go, mux

I want to handle the situation where a param wasn't defined.

```
import (
    // ...
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/connect", Connect).Methods("POST")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":7777", router))
}



// ...

func Connect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)

    if params["password"] == nil {
        fmt.Println("login without password")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("login with password")
    }
}
```

I also tried `if !params["ssid"] {`

What is the right syntax for this?

---

With `mux.Vars(r)` I'm trying to capture the post params from:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"ssid":"wifi"}' -X POST http://localhost:7777/connect
```

`ssid` is required but `password` is optional.

Comment: What framework/library are you using? What does mux.Vars return?

Comment: @CeriseLimón I updated the question with the params I'm trying to capture.

Comment: @Howl I'm using https://github.com/gorilla/mux

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride update your question to include the name (and a link) of the library you are using; otherwise people will have no idea what type `mux.Vars` is or how to help in general...

Comment: @maerics ok will do I assumed `mux` was a really popular library

Comment: It is, but don't assume anything unless it's the standard library (and even then it's better to specify) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following to check for presence of a mux request variable:

```
params := mux.Vars(r)   
password, ok := params["password"] 
if ok {
   // password is set
} else {
   // password is not set
}
```

This code uses [the two value index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) to check for presence of the key in the map.

It looks like your intent is to parse a JSON request body and not to access the mux variables.  Do this in your handler:

```
 var m map[string]string
 err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&m)
 if err != nil {
     // handle error
 }
 password, ok := m["password"]
 if ok {
   // password is set
 } else {
   // password is not set
 }
```

Comment: I think this would be correct if I was using params correctly(?) I don't know if it's right because when I post with and without a password the code inside `ok` runs but it just prints blank.